# HDD won't let windows boot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, bootable-media

First my system:
MB Gigabyte ax370m gaming 3
Ram 2x g.skill aegis 8gb
Cpu ryzen 5 1600
Psu corsair cx 600
Gpu msi gtx 960 2gb

1ssd ocz trion 256gb
1HDD seagate 1TB

The problem:
After a restart i made and after the bios message the pc stuck at windows logo for some 5 minutes i did 1 hard reset in order to get the repairing windows logo (after following a guide). Then immediately after the logo a cmd came really fast and disappeared with a black screen where i was stuck again. Ok disks i said, i removed the power from the HDD which it has windows on it but i only use it for storage and everything booted absolutely fine. Then i traded sata cables, nothing then sata ports still nothing. Then i removed the ssd and tried the Hdd alone it stuck at windows logo then the preparing automatic repair so i had no way to get into windows even for backup. Then i used a known good usb stick with windows iso on it using uefi in order to get to safe mode or restoration from windows installation procedure, it boots on the ssd or when no disk is in the system, but when the HDD is on, oh boy, i tried legacy/bios and after the MB message it ignores the usb... I have to make it a priority boot every time, then i used uefi and thats the furthest I've gotten after booting from usb instead of showing the windows installation procedure it just shows a purple screen with my Mouse moving. how can a Hdd create so many problems

Edit: i tried the hdd in a second system and it creates the exact same problems i know i it's not expensive to replace  but i have university exam stuff in there do you have any ideas?

Comment: _"Then i removed the ssd and tried the Hdd alone it stuck at windows logo"_ and _"i removed the power from the HDD ... and everything booted absolutely fine"_  :  So you have Windows installed on both, the HDD and SSD?

Comment: Yes i do i have installed windows 10 on both and the hdd have paid original version

Comment: You write in title "HDD won't let windows bootable usb boot" <-- This is gibberish.  Booting is BEFORE Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can a Hdd create so many problems

> but i have university exam stuff in there

Most likely your HDD has died, or about to die. The best you can do with it is to take it to a **data recovery** centre if the data is important.

> but when the HDD is on, oh boy, i tried legacy/bios and after the MB message it ignores the usb...

Some motherboards have a **SATA hotplug** capability somewhere in the BIOS Setup, which could be worth a try. It might look something like this -
[image: SATA Hotplug motherboard firmware setting]
*(Note: I don't own this image, [credits for image](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/8485/GB%207PESH3%20BIOS%2011%20-%20SATA%20Config.JPG))*

Enable this option, it allows drives to be connected/disconnected without shutting down the PC.
Then disconnect the HDD and boot from your SSD, and once Windows starts, connect the HDD SATA port again and try to browse it. If it's not detected, or if Windows freezes when it's connected, then data recovery might be the only option left for the HDD.

Comment: Welp it froze, so i will take it to a data recovery and i will edit the question whether they could recover it or not

Comment: Hmm, good luck!